# include javascript in wordpress

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm having a problem with a javascript that I want to include in a wordpress template page.

What I'm trying to do: 
On this page - http://www.pcworld.ro/vworker/ - I want to call a javascript that will fade-in/out 6 images (you can see the first image in the top right side of the header).

This is the script: http://www.pcworld.ro/vworker/wp-content/themes/visualtime/js/innerfade.js

This is what I have in header.php:

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script('innerfade', '/vworker/wp-content/themes/visualtime/js/innerfade.js', array('jquery'));?>
<?php wp_head();?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(
function(){
$('ul#screenshots').innerfade({
speed: 1000,
timeout: 4000,
type: 'random',
containerheight: '259px'
});
});
</script>
```

This is what I have in functions.php:

```
<?php
function load_scripts() {
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
   wp_enqueue_script('innerfade', '/wp-content/themes/visualtime/js/innerfade.js', array('jquery'));
}    
add_action('init', 'load_scripts');
?>
```

And this is the code that should be responsible for the javascript in homepage.php (the wordpress template page where I need the javascript to work):

```
<div id="screenshot" style="overflow:hidden;">
            <ul class="innerfade" id="screenshots" style="list-style: none outside none; margin: 0pt; padding: 0pt; cursor: pointer; position: relative; height: 259px;" onclick="location.href='#'"> 
                <li style="z-index: 6; position: absolute; display: none;">
                    <img src="/vworker/wp-content/themes/visualtime/images/productscreenshot1.jpg" alt="Room Booking System">
                </li>
                <li style="z-index: 5; position: absolute; display: none;">
                    <img src="/vworker/wp-content/themes/visualtime/images/productscreenshot2.jpg" alt="Complete Administration Panel">
                </li>
                <li style="z-index: 4; position: absolute; display: none;">
                    <img src="/vworker/wp-content/themes/visualtime/images/productscreenshot3.jpg" alt="Meeting Room Bookings">
                </li>
                <li style="z-index: 3; position: absolute; display: none;">
                    <img src="/vworker/wp-content/themes/visualtime/images/productscreenshot4.jpg" alt="View Statistics of All Room Bookings">
                </li>
                <li style="z-index: 2; position: absolute; display: none;">
                    <img src="/vworker/wp-content/themes/visualtime/images/productscreenshot5.jpg" alt="Including a Helpdesk System">
                </li>
                <li style="z-index: 1; position: absolute; display: list-item;">
                    <img src="/vworker/wp-content/themes/visualtime/images/productscreenshot6.jpg" alt="Intelligent Recurring Bookings">
                </li>
            </ul>
</div>
```

I'm a beginner when it comes to wordpress and an absolute noob when there's javascript involved. Could you please explain me what I'm doing wrong and to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is common among wordpress theme developers, they automatically include `jQuery.noConflict()` in jquery file to avoid collision with other libraries.
http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries

**Several choices:**

Remove `jQuery.noConflict();` from bottom of the jquery file
-or-
Replace `$` in all your code with the text `jQuery`. The plugin files you use should be insulated and are OK

-or-

Change

```
$(document).ready(
function(){ 
   //.........
}
```

to

```
jQuery(document).ready(
function($){
   //.........
}
```

WIth `$` as argument in ready you can use `$` inside it